# Calculation based on input / previous result in MySQL query without using SET / SP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `stock` table which I want to do some calculations to get eligible stock rows with appropriate qnty.

```
Stock

-----------------------------------------------------------------
| id |     item    | batch_number | expiry_date | current_stock | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   1         1         BAT-1-1      15 Jun 2016              10
   2         1         BAT-1-2      20 Jun 2016               5
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have input as `item = 1` & `quantity = 13`.

My Expected query output is

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |     item    | batch_number | expiry_date | current_stock | eligible |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1         1         BAT-1-1      15 Jun 2016              10         10
   2         1         BAT-1-2      20 Jun 2016               5          3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Logic :

1) Nearest expiry date is preferred

2) If the `current_stock >= input` -> `eligible = input`, else `eligible = current_stock` and decrement the input as `input -= eligible`

3) Repeat Step 2 on the next nearest expiry date with decemented input value until I've no more rows to process or I've got enough eligible quantities.

Is it possible in a mysql query without using SP or SET ? Bcoz I've to implement the resultant query in our Java application. I'm using Hibernate, so I may execute the query as sql or hql or criteria (if possible).

I've written a query for the above logic but without decrementing the input value for further calculations

```
SELECT
    id
    item,
    batch_number,
    expiry_date,
    current_stock,
    CASE WHEN current_stock >= 13 THEN 13 ELSE current_stock END AS eligible
FROM
    stock
WHERE
    item = 1
ORDER BY
    expiry_date
```

But it will not produce `eligible = 3` for the second row coz I've not decremented the input value after first row calculation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A solution like the one you're suggesting will scale poorly. Employing `@` variables will be more efficient

Comment: @Strawberry, If I employ `@variable`, then  is it possible for me to do concurrent query execution (I mean - Is `@variable` thread safe / concurrent safe ? ).

Comment: It's session specific, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not yet had my coffee, so my arithmetic may be a little off, but something like this should work...

```
SELECT x.*
     , GREATEST(@i,MOD(current_stock,@i)) eligible
     , @i:=GREATEST(@i-current_stock,0) i 
  FROM stock x
     , (SELECT @i:=13) vars 
 ORDER  
    BY expiry_date;
```

Comment: This works as expected.. Thanks..!! Just wondering if the same can be possible for multiple items with respective quantity (Eg: `[item - 1, qnty - 13], [item - 2, qnty - 17]`). I know it's possible to execute this query for every item using `where` clause for item, but I think only possible way for multiple items with qnty (in single query) is using SP..!! Any thoughts..!

Comment: I think that would need a sproc as you suggest - but maybe someone has another idea.

Comment: Done some changes in the query to get correct result.. Thank you for pointing in correct direction..